# Sort the rows in android database table

Tags: android, database, sorting

I have an Database table having three columns. The contents of this table are displayed using a list view.  I want the rows in the database to be arranged in ascending order of the values stored a particular column.

I want the database to be re-written instead of using ORDER BY clause.

Answer (score 2):

You can choose which column to sort by using the `ORDER BY` clause. Check out [the sqlite syntax](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_select.html) for more info.

Comment: As I understand, the ORDER BY clause returns the rows in the required order. I want the database to be rewritten in the required order

Comment: Although I do not fully understand why you would want to do this, you can of course create a new table with the sorted records retrieved with the above clause, drop the old and rename the new to the old name or something like that. Check [the docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteOpenHelper.html)!

Comment: Creating a new table and dropping the old will do the stuff. Thanks for the help buddy.